# Album art of music file

Tags: actionscript-3, blackberry-playbook

Is There any way by which we can have album art of any music file , i am able to extract file detail like album name , length , author , genre , track info.
But i am intresred in to showing album art image. 
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently someone on [this page](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=185677) managed to write some code to extract the image's data as a ByteArray, then finally load it through a Loader object. Here's the code they came up with:

```
var binaryData:ByteArray;
var file:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("test.mp3"));
var finalData:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
var byteCon:Loader = new Loader;
var offset:int; var rLength:int;
var found:Boolean = false;
var end:Boolean = false;
file.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
function handleComplete(e:Event):void{
    binaryData = file.data as ByteArray;
    binaryData.position = 0;
    //get offset and length
    while(!found){
        var pos:int = binaryData.readUnsignedInt();
        if(pos == 0x41504943){
            offset = binaryData.position + 20;
        }
        if(pos == 0){
            if (!found){
                rLength = binaryData.position - 1 - offset;
                if(rLength > 5000){
                    found = true;
                }
            }    
        }
        binaryData.position = binaryData.position - 3;
    }
    finalData.writeBytes(binaryData, offset, rLength);
    finalData.position = 0;
    byteCon.loadBytes(finalData);
    addChild(byteCon);
}
```

Of course this is talking about MP3s specifically, although you might be able to adapt it for other formats.

Comment: Will u please explain what is happening in this code, i am not able to get it?

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal Basically, it is reading through the actual binary data of the mp3 looking for the specific byte chunk that indicates an attached picture, and then extracts that and adds it to the display.

Comment: Yeah, Pixel Elephant's got that right. You can store the image in a DisplayObject such as a Sprite by passing byteCon into it.

Comment: Ok... But by accessing this sample code ,i was able to get very few files album art & all part of album art was not displayed,

Comment: Hmm, well I haven't tested it myself and personally I'm pretty inexperienced with working with bytes and ByteArrays so I can't help you much. Sorry.

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal, this code will only extract the image data if it is embedded in the mp3 file. If it's not then you need to take the file metadata and go find the image.

Comment: I have tried lots of another code .. in all i am getting this as most suitable answere.. Thanks a ton.